# Are there security risks in working directly in the themes folder that builds into a theme folder?

Tags: security, directory

I'm wondering if there are any security risks in using the wp-content/themes/ folder as my project root and using wp-content/themes/my-theme as my build folder. Basically, in the themes folder I would put my sass, scripts, gulp tasks, node_modules and anything else I will need that will ultimately be compiled/moved to the actual theme folder.

Comment: it is kind of a non question, build tools/enviroment do not belong to production or even staging. On your local development (for some flexible definition of local) you are not very likely to be attacked as hopefully you are behind a firewall or some similar protection